# Java CDI - how to create custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations, cdi

I feel stupid, but I fail to find at once explanation on how to create custom annotation for CDI.

I want to make my own version of `@Produces` which will allow pooling (i.e. it will return proxies allowing to access pool of objects). Or perhaps I'd better create annotation which should be added at injection point, telling to use pool...

Comment: In the end, do you care about the pool or do you care about getting one of the objects out of the pool?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is to modify a producer, is that correct? If so you'll need to do that with a portable extension listening to the `ProcessProducer` event.